# Visual Basic RSA Encryption

Tags: vb.net, encryption

Think I got it right this time ;)

I got the following code:

```
Sub encrypt()
    'Use UTF8 to convert the text string into a byte array
    textbytes = encoder.GetBytes(TextToEncrypt)
    'encrypt the text
    encryptedtextbytes = rsa.Encrypt(textbytes, True)
    'Convert the encrypted byte array into a Base64 string for display purposes
    encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedtextbytes)
End Sub

Sub decrypt()

    encryptedtextbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(TextToDecrypt)
    'get the decrypted clear text byte array
    textbytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedtextbytes, True)
    'convert the byte array to text using the same encoding format that was used for encryption
    decrypted = encoder.GetString(textbytes)
End Sub
```

But where can I use my public key for this encryption? Because every time I close the application, I cannot decrypt the text I encrypted earlier using this code. The thing I am trying to accomplish is to encrypt a file using my public key, send it to a server, and decrypt it over there with my private key.

Comment: RSA cannot encrypt a plaintext longer than its key.

Comment: @SLaks I did not know that. But I could always encrypt files using my public key with programs like Kleopatra

Comment: @JanHoi Look into [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Something like this? http://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/examples/encrypt-file/ Do happen to know if there's a free alternative to this?

Comment: Kleopatra is only a front end for GPG. GPG performs OpenPGP encryption. To do the same thing, use an OpenPGP compatible library for your language. For .NET there is Bouncy Castle (it targets C#, but as it is a .NET library, it may also work with Visual Basic). OpenPGP also uses hybrid encryption.